# Storing CGColorRef in NSArray as Pointer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, core-graphics

I get confused sometimes when working with CG elements, and have the following scenario that seems simple but is giving me trouble.

I have a `CGColorRef` property called `fillColor`, for which I manually define the setter method as follows:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGColorRef fillColor;

- (void) setFillColor:(CGColorRef)fillColor
{
    CGColorRetain(fillColor); 
    CGColorRelease(_fillColor); 
    _fillColor = fillColor;
}
```

After I `_fillColor` to some value, I store it in an array as follows:

```
_fillColors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)_fillColor, nil];
```

I'd like it so that when change `self.fillColor`, I'd like it for the value in the array to change also. I could obviously make a pointer, ie `CGColorRef *fillColor`, but in doing that how would I manage the memory (ie release, retain it) and how would my setter method change? This is really confusing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>`NSArray` copies its objects.</del>  `NSArray` will receive a copy of the pointer you pass in.  That means you get a copy of a pointer to a `CGColor` struct (Yes, `CGColorRef` is already a pointer).  So changing either one will never have any effect on the other.  Storing a pointer to the `CGColorRef` seems to be the only way, other than using `NSPointerArray` (which is only iOS 6+).

**EDIT**: The end result was making a class that contained all the information in one place (path, color, etc) and storing a pointer to that instead.

Comment: How would you manage the memory for the pointer, I think that is confusing me quite a bit, would my setter method change at all (other than the pointer syntax)

Comment: ie, would it now become an object from which the property I would retain?

Comment: I think you might want to rethink the logic of your app.  Why do you need to store things in this manner?  I just tried adding a pointer to an NSArray and it won't let me so things will get much more complicated.

Comment: I have some arrays that store drawing data for some graphics, ie a bunch of mutablePaths with their corresponding fill and stroke data. I'd like for the user to change colors without having to reload all of the data for the graphic.

Comment: Make a class that stores that data and store IT in an array.

Comment: Thanks that worked, can you update answer to reflect storing in it's own class and THEN making it into a pointer.

Comment: NSArray copies its objects? Is there a reference for that?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Terrible wording on my part, I apologize.  What I meant was, the *pointer* gets copied into the array (since it is a stack object), so it holds a new pointer to the same object that was added, but changing one pointer will not have an effect on the other.